# generic enum with switch swift

Tags: swift, enums

I have the following enum

```
enum MoneyCupUsersBackEndRouter: URLRequestConvertible {

    case getInfo
    case postUserConnection(ConnectionData)
    case postPersonalInfo(UserUpdatePersonalInformationsRequest)
    case postKycAnswers(QuestionnaireAnswers)

    switch self {
        case .postUserConnection(let parameters):
            let r = parameters.encode()
            print(r)

        case .postPersonalInfo(let parameters):
            let r = parameters.encode()
            print(r)

        case .postKycAnswers(let parameters):
            let r = parameters.encode()
            print(r)

        default:
            break
        }
```

This code is quite ugly, I had to duplicate the cases in the switch since each time, parameters are of a different type. But all of the paramaters follow the 'Codable' protocole.

There must be a way to avoid that by using some sort of generic types.

All the encode functions are declared like the following one :

```
func encode() -> [String: Any] {
   return ["id": id, "data": data]
}
```

The returned dictionnary contains the struc fields.

Comment: Do those parameters (ConnectionData, UserUpdatePersonalInformationsRequest, QuestionnaireAnswers) have something in common?

Comment: They are encodable struct or String

Comment: Unless I am overlooking something, `Decodable` does not require a `encode()` method.

Comment: @user3239711 `Decodable` doesn't have an `encode()` method, where is that coming from?

Comment: My mistake, Codable

Comment: @user3239711: Then you have a `encode(to:) throws` method, not a `encode()` method. Please post your real code.

Comment: Actually, it is a legacy code. So an encode function has been defined for each Struct

Comment: So how do you expect to call `encode()` on different types if its a custom method implemented individually for all these types? You could just move this `encode()` method to a protocol, but without seeing the actual function it's hard to tell for sure. Please [edit] your question to include the definition for the three associated types and `encode()`.

Comment: I don' think this is possible (at least in version 4.1). If you do `case .a(let x as Encodable), .b(let x as Encodable), .c(let x as Encodable):` then there is an error saying "Matching a protocol value in multiple patterns is not yet supported; use separate cases instead". Don't know about Swift 4.2 though.

Comment: @Sweeper: It does compile in Xcode 10 (and happens to be what I prepared as an answer :) – but I am reluctant to post it before OP shows actual compiling code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all associated types conform to a common protocol `Foo` (which has the `encode()`
method as a requirement) then you can use the `as Foo` pattern for the associated values to combine all cases to a single one.

Here is a self-contained example (tested with Xcode 10/Swift 4.2):

```
protocol Foo {
    func encode() -> [String: Any]
}

class A: Foo {
    func encode() -> [String: Any] { return ["A": 1] }
}

class B: Foo {
    func encode() -> [String: Any] { return ["B": 2] }
}

class C: Foo {
    func encode() -> [String: Any] { return ["C": 3] }
}

enum MyEnum {

    case a(A)
    case b(B)
    case c(C)

    func test() {
        switch self {
        case .a(let parameters as Foo),
            .b(let parameters as Foo),
            .c(let parameters as Foo):

            let r = parameters.encode()
            print(r)

        }
    }
}

MyEnum.a(A()).test() // ["A": 1]
MyEnum.b(B()).test() // ["B": 2]
MyEnum.c(C()).test() // ["C": 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is an encodable parameter, you could try this -

```
case getInfo
case postUserConnection(Codable)
case postPersonalInfo(Codable)
case postKycAnswers(Codable)
```

Then -

```
func stuff() {
    switch self {
    case .postUserConnection(let parameters), .postPersonalInfo(let parameters), .postKycAnswers(let parameters):
        let r = try? parameters.encode()
        print(r as Any)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

But of course you may need the different types you currently have as the associated values, then this wouldn't be possible.